# Jersey-Spring3 maven dependency issue

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I have declared jersey-spring3 dependency for my jersey2 rest application in pom.xml as follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

After including this in POM, maven dependency problem is shown in eclipse as follows:

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:jar:>2.6: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:pom:>2.6 from/to release.maven.java.net (https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public):
```

Here is my complete pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.adaequare</groupId>
<artifactId>springjerseysample</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Jersey Sample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jersey.version>2.6</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>springjerseysample</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>release.maven.java.net</id>
        <name>java.net Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I have gone to the repository URL and have found the dependency there. Not sure why it says that it can not read it. I have tried deleting the folder from my local repository and doing a maven clean. But even it did not work.

Also I have tried doing mvn clean install -U also but of no use. It says it cannot find in both the respositories: Maven central repository and release.mavaen.java.net repository. What causes this issue?

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you post your eclipse and maven versions? Also have you tried it from the command line instead of eclipse as eclipse may be caching a local version of this file.

    Downloaded: https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-spring3/2.6/jersey-spring3-2.6.pom (7 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 and Maven 2.2.1

Comment: I have downloaded the jar from repository and tried to do mvn install:install-file to the local repository. But even that did not work. May I know the version of maven and eclipse you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. There is actually a problem with dependency definition. There is an additional character '>' in the version field of jersey-spring3 dependency. Once I removed it, it is working fine.